# PowerPC No OS How to install with USB

Tags: installation, powerpc

I have a PowerPC G3 that does not have an OS on it. I dont have a disk, but I do have an USB. I plug it in but I am not getting anything to install

Comment: Not every computer can boot from USB. Check out the [PowerPC options](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/powerpc/ch05s01.html).

Answer (score 1):

I recently got a usb to boot on an ibook g3.

You very likely already know this, but some "regular" iso's don't work for powerpc's. Rather one needs a different iso (look for PPC) : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/PreviousReleases

I do recommend the "alternate" iso as I found it to install faster.

I found the following very helpful :

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#How_do_I_boot_from_a_USB_drive.3F

it looks really long, but that's because it addresses lots of things that could go wrong!

Being fairly command-line illiterate, I found the "dd" command discussed somewhat of a challenge to use, but after several tries at getting the path correct, it worked just fine. (Do note that it may take a while, with no indication of activity in the terminal).

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you go to the start-up options by pressing ESC at the beginning, when you start your system and the name of your system manufacturer appears on the screen then from there go to the boot menu and over there choose your USB whichever one it is (eg: Kingston data traveller....), then you'd be able to boot from you're pen drive.